# font-size: does not work for GWT button and flextable

Tags: gwt

How do you change the font size in a GWT Button or a GWT Flextable?

The standard CSS of 
font-size: 150%; does not work, but 
color: red; does work.

Also, font-family does not work for flexible (but does for button)

I am new to GWT. thanks Bob.

Comment: How are you setting the font size? Using CSS in a ClientBundle or UIBinder template? Or procedurally in your code. Can you provide a code sample of what you're doing?

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
font-size: 18px
```

or

```
font-size: 2em
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change the style that way:

```
font-size: 150% !important;
```